# Loading previously elapsed time with Pygame and Pickle

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, pygame, pickle

I'm making a game that's very dependent on elapsed time. My current implementation works based off of pygame.time.get_ticks() and is very simple and easy; here's a small example:

```
if event.type == DISPTIMER:
        time = int(pygame.time.get_ticks()/1000)
        timeObj = buttonFont.render(str(time) + ' seconds since start', False, black)
        windowSurfaceObj.blit(timeObj, (450, 50))
```

However, I'm unsure how to go about pickling this. I've searched all through the pygame documentation and can't find any way to write to pygame's time module.
I could use a clock, but I can't find any way to read a clock's value without resetting it, which makes it unsuitable for my purposes.

Is there any way to do this without unwieldy work-arounds?

Comment: You can't overwrite time in PyGame.

Comment: You'll probably need to pickle the saved time and add it to the time returned by `get_ticks()`, though that might fall into the "unwieldy work-around" category.

Comment: Yes, I figured. I guess what I'm looking for is any input on what else I could use other than pygame's time, that would be well-suited to the kind of tasks pygame's time is good for but could be pickled and loaded.

edit:
Dano, that seems like a likely candidate. I can probably make that work with only an extra line and variable.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by this? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Sure.
This is an idle game. The primary purpose of the elapsed time is as user feedback; I want to report to players how long they've been playing. It's a useful metric from a usability perspective, and it's also relevant from a competitive standpoint.

Also, certain things happen in-game after an elapsed number of seconds, and restoring elapsed time when a game is loaded prevents altering game outcome and behaviour through saving and loading. This could also be accomplished with individual tickers, but in a game where lots of things are timed this is unwieldy.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I figured out what you are trying to do.

If I am not mistaken, you want to be able to load and save the ticks since the start of the game. For this you can use `pygame.time.Clock` and an extra variable that will store the `passed_ticks`.

Here is an example:

```
passed_ticks = 0
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# somewhere in your main loop
passed_ticks += clock.tick()

# printing becomes
if event.type == DISPTIMER:
    time = int(passed_ticks/1000)
    timeObj = buttonFont.render(str(time) + ' seconds since start', False, black)
    windowSurfaceObj.blit(timeObj, (450, 50))
```

You can now save and load your `passed_ticks` variable anytime.

Comment: I ended up doing something more like dano's suggestion: time = int((pygame.time.get_ticks()+savedTime)/1000). But thanks!